# Getting a windows 7 box as reliable as possible

Tags: windows-7, windows, performance, debian

We're looking to use an existing (decent) windows 7 box in a small theatre for sound playback and possibly some video (using http://www.showcuesystems.com/ mainly). I'm a mac and debian guy normally but am happy to dig around in windows.

My main concern with this setup is reliability of the OS and other "background fluff", what can I do to make this box rock solid and reliable?

My plan so far is to do a clean install, then disable any unneeded services/startup items etc.

Comment: Use windows update in control panel to get it fully patched, including optional updates that are for "reliability" and compatibility, avoid driver updates from windows updates if it is an OEM PC.

Comment: Are you using the Media Center edition of Windows 7?  Perhaps that has features you could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run as standard user.  Nuff said.  Spend the rest of your tweaking time on actual productivity.

Comment: It's Windows 7. _Unless_ you log in as the account named "Administrator", everything you do is as a 'normal user' by default. You have to answer a prompt in order to elevate your privileges.

Comment: The point is that attitude, not implementation, will earn you a "reliable" box. UAC prompts will not stop the inadvertent click of "Yes, I want to do this. Yes, I want to do that." Research will surprise you on how often people click Yes/OK without reading the prompt.

Comment: Yes we'll be doing that anyway as there will be many people using the box who I don't really trust so...

Comment: @will: Well untrusted users it a TOTALLY different issue!

Comment: They're not too bad, and the box does spend most of it's time off a network.

Comment: Oh! I didn't understand the original question I guess then. A search on using Windows 7 as a Kiosk machine would be handy. I've seen machines setup for that kind of thing, but have not done it myself and yes you certainly wouldn't make the user an admin user. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-can-i-setup-a-computer-with-windows-7-to-be/89f3246f-baaf-45fc-b946-07450475a5b0

Answer (score 1):

Get the computer the way you want it, running fine... remove everything unneeded and clone it. Use clonezilla, ping, acronis, ghost whatever. Another way is to use something like [SteadyState](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24373) (group policy), [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/enterprise/deep-freeze/). Somebody will mess it up sooner or later. And its easier to recover via image than spending hours trying to fix something and then ending up reinstalling anyways.